# cant install Citext on Postgres 10 aws

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

Having difficulties implementing extension **Citext** in Postgres **10.1** on **aws** ec2 instance.

**1- Tried "Create extension citext;"**

--ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/pgsql/share/extension/citext.control": No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01

**2- Tried to install, postgresql-contrib.**

--Not found

**3- Installed postgresql96-contrib (older version), then tried to copy extension files** (using ec2-user root account) from "usr/share/psql96/extenson" to "/usr/local/pgsql/share/extension".

-- Access denied

Linux newbie, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using amazon ec2 instance running amazon linux ami, try installing the postgresql-contrib package on this instance,

**sudo yum install postgresql-contrib**

Now below command from psql prompt should work,

**CREATE EXTENSION citext;**